# Algorithm: How to find the number of solutions to SAT?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, sat, satisfiability

Assume that the number of variables N and the number of clauses K are equal. Find an algorithm that returns the number of different ways to satisfy the clauses.

I read that SAT is related to Independent Sets.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @GeorgSchölly No, it's not homework. I'm learning algorithms to prepare for job interviews.

Comment: Does this come under #P (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P?) I know you have a restriction that the number of variables is equal to the number of clauses, whereas I would normally expect more clauses than variables. However a problem with few variables could always be padded out by adding clauses such as (X|Y|Z|...) where X,Y,Z... are variables not previously used.

Answer (score 2):

A function with `N` variables has a [truth-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) with `2^N` rows. Each row corresponds to one [minterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms) which can be either a solution or not.

A clause with `N` variables excludes exactly one of the [minterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms) as part of the solutions. That is the [minterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms) which consists of all inverted variables of the clause.

Provided, the `K` clauses are all different,

> the number of solutions is 2^N - K

---

**Example:**

The `K=3` clauses with `N=3` variables:

```
 A or  B or  C
!A or  B or  C
 A or  B or !C
```

The truth-table for three inputs:

```
A  B  C  output
0  0  0  0         //  excluded by A or B or C
0  0  1  0         //  excluded by A or B or !C
0  1  0  1
0  1  1  1
1  0  0  0         //  excluded by !A or B or C     
1  0  1  1
1  1  0  1
1  1  1  1
```

Five of the possible eight terms remain true. Thus, the example has 2^3 - 3 = 5 solutions.